# Parents are Rh +ve and child Rh -ve

Tags: hematology, blood-group

Suppose the two parents of a child have blood groups A+ve and O+ve, and the child has O-ve type. For blood group, there are two alleles. Since the child has O, the father must have one 'A' allele and one 'O' allele.

Does such a reasoning hold for the Rhesus factor too? Should I interpret that both the parents have one + allele and one - allele?

Comment: Since the Rhesus antigen is inherited in a dominant negative way, both of your parents need to be heterozygote for it, so you can carry -/- for your alleles.

Comment: I edited the question to remove reference to self. Good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rhesus antigen (Rh-D) is inherited in an **autosomal dominant** pattern.  Therefore you are correct in your reasoning.

Simple problems like this are often best worked out using Punnet Squares, shown below for the scenarios you have considered.

---

Because the inheritance pattern is dominant, if *either* parent was homozygous (DD) for Rh-D then 100% of their offspring will be Rh+ve.

[image: Punnet square for Rhesus disease with homozygous positive and negative parents]

In order to have a rhesus negative child, *neither* parent must be homozygous for the D allele.  You are correct that one possible scenario is a matching pair of heterozygotes:

[image: Rhesus inheritance punnet square for matching heterozygote parents]

In this situation 3/4 of the children are rhesus positive and 1/4 rhesus negative.

There is an alternative where one parent is Rhesus negative and the other positive.  In this case there is one heterozygous parent and one homozygous negative parent:

[image: Punnet square for rhesus inheritance with one homozygote negative and one heterozygote]

In this scenario, half of the children are rhesus positive and half rhesus negative.

Comment: Thanks. The second case does not arise because the mother is Rh- positive, in my question.

Comment: @Bravo ah of course, I missed that element!